# interface X extends ScrollElementProps<P> = P & {}

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-scroll

I'm working with [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll). There is a props type alias which looks like this:

```
export type ScrollElementProps<P> = P & {
    name: string;
    id?: string | undefined;
};
```

I'm trying to extend the prop type, but I think I'm doing it backwards. I tried:

```
interface MyElementProps extends ScrollElementProps {...}
```

but of course it's telling me: `Generic type 'ScrollElementProps' requires 1 type argument(s)`

How do I write this so that my interface recognizes the props expected by the `ScrollElementProps` type alias?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I figured it out as soon as I posted the question!

This type alias was built to expect a props interface/alias, so this is how it should look:

```
interface ScrollProps {
  myProps: string
  someMoreProps: boolean
}

export const Scroll = ({

  myProps,
  someMoreProps,

}: ScrollElementProps<ScrollProps>) => {
   ...
}
```